# Win32 streaming API and the DMZ

Tags: sql, api, streaming, filestream

We are investigating the use of the Win32 streaming API to pull out files stored with the FILESTREAM capabilities in SQL 08.  If a web application, sitting on the public side of the firewall uses the streaming API to pull back a file, what ports must be opened to make this happen?

Also, are there any NTFS file/directory permission issues to be concerned with?  Or does the fact it is stored via SQL Server circumvent those problems you typically encounter?

Answer (score 0):

Filestream uses SMB for remote blob access, so whatever ports are required by SMB must be open. File/directory permissions should not be a concern, since the access control is managed by SQL Server based on sql permission model.